# WatchKit session is reachable but message never sends

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, watch

In a watch app I'm sending a heart rate string to an iPhone app, which is successfully connected and open. In the below code the "Message Dict" part is hit and logged (i.e. the session is reachable) but the message never sends nor logs any error / reply dict. I'm not sure if this is an iOS 14 issue because this code used to work fine, it's also exactly what's in Apple's docs.

Has anyone else experienced this? Thank you for the help!

```
func sendHeartRateString(theString: String) {
    if WCSession.default.isReachable {
      let messageDict = ["HR": theString]
      
      print("--- MESSAGE DICT \(messageDict)")

      WCSession.default.sendMessage(messageDict, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
        print("--- RD HR \(replyDict)")
      }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        print("--- ER HR \(error)")
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you activated the session? ie. is the session state `WCSessionActivationState.activated`?

Comment: Yes I have and it is activated.